# How do I safeguard usage of React components that might not exist?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

In my project I will possibly get icons/svgs as react components in a folder generated by the backend. There will also be a WAMP (bonefish/autobahn) solution where I get the name of an icon to use (I know this is a bit weird but just let it be that way).

They will place all icons in a folder on an embedded unit, and I will have to get the icons from there. The icons will be exported in a index file and imported where I need them.

structure will be something like this:

```
.
├─ src
├─── buttonManagement.tsx
|
├─ incons
├─── index.ts
├─── iconA.tsx
├─── iconB.tsx
|
.
.
```

index.ts

```
export * from "iconA";
export * from "iconB";
```

in buttonManagement i then can import all icons and use them like this. I can not use the notation icons.iconName since this is done in runtime and I cant import things I do not know the name of.

```
import * as icons from "../icons"

const icon = icons["iconA"];
```

So far so good, but what do I do when backend sends an icon name that does not exist?

```
const icon = icons["iconC"];
```

then I get this error

```
Property 'iconC' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/home/ubuntu/workspace/code/myProject/icons/index")'
```

How do I do this?

I tried using try/catch

this does not work either

```
const iconC = icons["iconC"] as React.ComponentType | undefined;
```

Comment: `(icons as any).iconC`

Comment: @Konrad that was an easy fix! :) it works, but if you add it as an answer and not a comment that would be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you are trying to access an `icon` that does not exist when compile. You can define the type of `Icons` like below and casting type to `icons` and return it if the `iconC` is valid then you complete fine when compiling.

```
import * as icons from "../icons"

type Icons = {[key:string]:React.ComponentType} 

const IconC= (icons as Icons)['IconC']

return <>{IconC && <IconC />}</>
```